# Array of objects via parameters in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I could able to `POST` the `parameters` as follows, it works if I have only one item for each dictionary item. In the following params I have only one `pName` and one `price`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
                             @{@"pName":pData.pName, 
                             @"price":pData.price,
                             @"notes":pData.notes}];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html",nil];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:URL_SIGNIN parameters:params progress: nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
 }
 failure:
 ^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
```

However, I wonder how could I able to put items as a parameters if I have more than one items such as `pNames = [Beef, Coffee, Rice ,Sprite]` and `prices = ["$10", $"3", "$5", @"1"]`.

Consider as following object at the end.

```
orders = {@"Beef" : @"$10",@"Coffee" : @"$3", @"Rice" : @"$5", @"Sprite" : @"$1"}
```

Assume that it is restaurant application where user selects multiple items to check out.

Comment: Depending on the doc of your Web API: `NSArray *params = @[ @{@"pName":pData.pName,  @"price":pData.price, @"notes":pData.notes},@{@"pName":pData2.pName,  @"price":pData2.price, @"notes":pData2.notes}, etc. ];` or `NSDictionary *params = @{@"pName":@[pData.pName,pData2.pName, etc] ,  @"price":@[pData.price, pData2.price, etc] , @"notes":@[pData.notes, pData2.notes, ...]}`, but first solution seems more logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot Larme, appreciated for introducing object oriented way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an array (`$[]`), not a dictionary (`${}`).

In your example:

```
prices = @[@"$10", @"$3", @"$5", @"$1"];
```

EDIT:

As parameters:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
                             @{@"prices": @[@"$10", @"$3", @"$5", @"$1"]}];
```

OR:

```
NSArray *prices = @[@"$10", @"$3", @"$5", @"$1"];
NSMutableDictionary *params= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
                                 @{@"prices": prices];
```

Comment: How am  I going to put them as a parameters?

Comment: Is there a better way to solve problem with as an object `orders = {@"Beef" : @"$10",@"Coffee" : @"$3", @"Rice" : @"$5", @"Sprite" : @"$1"}` or should I separate them with price and name?

Comment: I cannot answer your project specific question, just the one you asked :)

Comment: Thanks Kurt, I am going to test it tonight and let you know. I need to sit with backend developer.